# Как с помощью цикла for вывести элементы по убыванию от 4 до 1?

Tags: php

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
 echo $i.'<br/>';    
}
```

выведет:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Как сделать что бы было наоборот т.е `4 3 2 1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Задать обратный счетчик

```
for ($i = 4; $i >= 0; $i--)
{
 echo $i.'<br/>';    
}
```

Только это не сортировка, а обратный вывод массива.

Если не нужно включать `0` в вывод, требуется убрать у условия `$i >= 0` знак `=`

---

Можно с помощью `while`

```
$i = 5;
while ($i--) {
  echo $i . "<br />";
}

Вывод: 4<br />3<br />2<br />1<br />0<br />
```

Comment: А можно и так `for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
 echo (4-$i).'<br/>';    
} `

Comment: @KoVadim лишняя итерация с вычислением, тогда уж брать while. Добавил в ответ

Answer (score 2):

Если вычитать из максимального значения текущее значения счетчика([как советует @KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533657/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0-for-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%82-4-%D0%B4%D0%BE-1#comment667926_533660)), также будет выводиться в обратном порядке

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    echo (4-$i).'<br/>';    
} 
// 4-0 = 4
// 4-1 = 3
// 4-2 = 2
// 4-3 = 1
// 4-4 = 0
```